# Under what condition, the limit of the integral of product of periodic functions vanishes.

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose I have two sinusoidal functions, $\sin(\omega_1 t)$ and $\sin(\omega_2 t)$. Under what condtion on $\omega_1 , \omega_2$, we can have the limit on the integral $$\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \frac{\sin(\omega_1 t)}{\sin(\omega_2 t)} \, dt =0 $$